# How do I test a ClusterIssuer solver?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I'm attempting to deploy a Kubernetes cluster with an SSL certificate using LetsEncrypt on DigitalOcean. I followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-on-digitalocean-kubernetes-using-helm), and everything works right up until the challenge order is created by the ClusterIssuer. Then I get this error:

```
cert-manager/controller/orders "msg"="Failed to determine the list of Challenge resources needed for the Order" "error"="no configured challenge solvers can be used for this challenge" "resource_kind"="Order" "resource_name"="letsencrypt-prod-cert-458163912-1173127706"
```

I've tried it both with http, and trying to configure DigitalOcean's `dns01` resolver, but neither work, and with a similar error. The site is live by ip, by dns name (though I get the no-ssl cert warning). This is the ClusterIssuer description:

```
Name:         letsencrypt-issuer
Namespace:
Labels:       app/instance=webapp
              app/managed-by=Tiller
              app/name=webapp
              app/version=0.1.0
              helm.sh/chart=webapp-0.1.0
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-issuer
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              kubernetes.io/tls-acme: true
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
Kind:         ClusterIssuer
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-10-16T23:24:47Z
  Generation:          2
  Resource Version:    10300992
  Self Link:           /apis/cert-manager.io/v1alpha2/clusterissuers/letsencrypt-issuer
  UID:                 2ee08cd4-5781-4126-9e6d-6b9d108a1eb2
Spec:
  Acme:
    Email:  <redacted>
    Private Key Secret Ref:
      Name:  letsencrypt-prod-cert
    Server:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
Status:
  Acme:
    Last Registered Email:  <redacted>
    Uri:                    https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/69503670
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2019-10-16T23:24:48Z
    Message:               The ACME account was registered with the ACME server
    Reason:                ACMEAccountRegistered
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

Is there a way to see the solvers themselves to validate they're configured correctly? Is there a way to exercise them to prove they work? Is there some other way to diagnose what the situation is? I'm completely stuck, as there doesn't seem to be a lot of support online for this?

Comment: The acme challenge has to be fulfilled for this validation, have a look at [this](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/reference/challenges.html) for more info

Comment: @TusharMahajan I have looked at that. Alas, it is not succeeding because of the above issue. Notably, that page has a big 'ol TODO where it says 'Troubleshooting failing challenges', which is why I've come here to SO. :/

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, I just implemented this TLS implementation via jetstack but I haven't used acme challenge for it, as my certificate got issued without that only and I have implemented it with kubernetes only.  Shall I share the approach to get the TLS encryption ?

Comment: My acme challenge got solved at level of ingress rule only. I can share details

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
 metadata:
  name: certificate-name
spec:
  secretName: tls-cert
  duration: 24h
  renewBefore: 12h
  commonName: hostname
  dnsNames:
  - hostname
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

---

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    email: myemail@email.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-private-key
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
      selector: {}
```

---

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: http01
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
  name: ingress-rule
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostname
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-service
          servicePort: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - hostname
    secretName: tls-cert
```

---

The above cited approach worked for me, tls-cert is automatically generated in the intended namespace, the key and certificate both. For this to happen, you should point the IP of nginx loadbalancer to DNS

It worked for me, the acme challenge will get auto tested and the certificate will change it status from false to true, once this gets done

Comment: Can you explain that last sentence about the IP of the nginx loadbalancer? What do you mean by 'point it to the DNS'?

Comment: In kubernetes, you would be exposing nginx controller to Load balancer and the externalIP has to be mapped to the hostname, I do that in azure in a service called DNS zone

Comment: Oh, I see; yes, the DNS is pointed to the Load Balancer's external port.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked; specifically it looked like the `solver` stanza was incorrect, and I needed to have an `http01` block both there and as an immediate child of `acme`. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: After recent cert-manager update to [v.0.11](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/upgrading/upgrading-0.10-0.11/) `http01` is moved to `solvers`. Also both API and API group were changed.

Comment: My Nginx load balancer is pointing to Load Balancer 80:32627/TCP,443:32535/TCP.      Then I need to expose my service to 32627 or 32535 ???? Currently I am port and target port are 8445 and 30445