# Jetstack cert-manager and GKE private cluster (failed to verify ACME account)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

I have installed the Jetstack cert-manager within my private GKE cluster. That all went well, but I can't get a certificate issued. The error that I get is:

```
E1101 03:45:15.754642       1 sync.go:184] cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="wrong status code '404', expected '200'" "dnsName"="[snip]" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="[snip]-certificate-2096248848-189663135-2951658629" "resource_namespace"="default" "type"="http-01" 
I1101 03:45:15.755017       1 controller.go:135] cert-manager/controller/challenges "level"=0 "msg"="finished processing work item" "key"="default/[snip]-certificate-2096248848-189663135-2951658629" 
I1101 03:45:25.755400       1 controller.go:129] cert-manager/controller/challenges "level"=0 "msg"="syncing item" "key"="default/[snip]-certificate-2096248848-189663135-2951658629" 
I1101 03:45:25.755810       1 pod.go:58] cert-manager/controller/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensurePod "level"=0 "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver pod" "dnsName"="[snip]" "related_resource_kind"="Pod" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-b6k59" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="[snip]-certificate-2096248848-189663135-2951658629" "resource_namespace"="default" "type"="http-01" 
I1101 03:45:25.755897       1 service.go:43] cert-manager/controller/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureService "level"=0 "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver Service for challenge resource" "dnsName"="[snip]" "related_resource_kind"="Service" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-qsvbv" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="[snip]-certificate-2096248848-189663135-2951658629" "resource_namespace"="default" "type"="http-01" 
I1101 03:45:25.755960       1 ingress.go:91] cert-manager/controller/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureIngress "level"=0 "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver ingress" "dnsName"="[snip]" "related_resource_kind"="Ingress" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-br7d2" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="[snip]-certificate-2096248848-189663135-2951658629" "resource_namespace"="default" "type"="http-01"
```

This corresponds with an error event in the `ClusterIssuer` that I deployed:

> Warning  ErrVerifyACMEAccount  27m (x4 over 28m)  cert-manager  Failed to verify ACME account: Get https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory: dial tcp: i/o timeout

Because of this my `CertificateRequest` and `Certificate` resources perpetually stay in a "pending" state.

This is happening during initial cluster creation. My configuration for the certificate manager & ingress is as follows:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-uat
spec:
  acme:
    email: cert-manager+uat@[snip]
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-uat-private-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: [snip]-uat-certificate
spec:
  secretName: [snip]-uat-tls-cert
  duration: 2160h
  renewBefore: 360h
  commonName: [snip]
  dnsNames:
  - [snip]
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-uat
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: [snip]-uat-tls-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-uat
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: [snip]
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: [snip]-uat-webapp-service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - [snip]
    secretName: [snip]-uat-tls-cert
```

I am on a GKE private cluster and have therefore also been unable to run the webhook component. The documentation seems to imply that this it's OK, but not recommended, to run this way.

Also, I note that the documentation references the need to add a firewall rule to allow the webhook to work. And I wonder if that is also relevant here? The error above seems to indicate some kind of networking (firewall?) related issue.

**Environment details:**:
GKE (1.14.7-gke.10)
Kubernetes (v1.16.2) (I think)
cert-manager (0.11.0)

Installed with `kubectl`

Do I need to configure a firewall rule, perhaps?

Many thanks,
Ben

**Edit 1:**

The "dial tcp: i/o timeout" is a red herring. That error persists only as long as the DNS takes to initialise with my cluster. I am also coming closer to the conclusion that the propagation error is simply LetsEncrypt DNS not seeing my domain associated with my IP address (yet).

Is it correct that I use an A record here? I made the DNS update around an hour ago - is there any way that I can see what LetsEncrypt's DNS sees?

Comment: If you have not placed any WAF then this issue doesn't pertain to that.  Did you try adding  "certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: http01", this annotation too , in ingress rule ?

Comment: I did have that annotation set, but this (https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.11/tasks/upgrading/upgrading-0.10-0.11.html) says that annotation is now deprecated, so I removed it. When I did have it declared I had the same problem, but I'll put it back in.

Comment: Could you please make sure that this is not DNS related issue. Please redeploy kube-dns in case the current kube-dns is down. Also, have a look into the following [GitHub post](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/624)

Comment: Thanks hachemon. I re-deployed by entire cluster from scratch and kube-dns is running. However, when following the GitHub posts' recommendation to check DNS, when I try to run any command on the cert-manager node I get:

"OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"nslookup\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown"

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks both for your help. It turns out that this was nothing to do with cert-manager. I had two issues in play here:

1. There was a GCP issue at the time that I was doing this to do with networks (this just caused confusion);
2. My application was not responding correctly the the HTTP challenge.

However, in the end, for other reasons, I decided to use the DNS solver. This worked just fine.

Thanks again!