# kubernetes certs not working with let's encrypt cert-manager

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I can't seem to get cert-manager working:

```
$ kubectl get certificates -o wide
NAME         READY   SECRET       ISSUER        STATUS                                         AGE
tls-secret   False   tls-secret   letsencrypt   Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist   115m

$ kubectl get CertificateRequest -o wide
NAME               READY   ISSUER        STATUS                                                                                        AGE
tls-secret-xxxx   False   letsencrypt   Referenced "ClusterIssuer" not found: clusterissuer.cert-manager.io "letsencrypt" not found   113m
```

my certificate.yaml is :

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: tls-secret
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: tls-secret
  dnsNames:
  - aks-xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.aksapp.io
  acme:
    config:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          name: xxxxxx
      domains:
      - aks-xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.aksapp.io
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

When i get cluster issuers

```
  $ kubectl get clusterissuers
    No resources found
```

any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have not created the **clusterissuers** so it wont be there.

As you have created the **certificate** you can try the

```
kubectl get certificate
```

Your error is clearly saying the issue you have to create the **clusterissuers**

> Referenced "ClusterIssuer" not found: clusterissuer.cert-manager.io
> "letsencrypt" not found

Cert-manager site : https://cert-manager.io/docs/

Installation : https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/

in single line just apply :

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.5.3/cert-manager.yaml
```

how to configure & setup the **clusterissuer** : https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/

Example of `cluster issuer` & `ingress`

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: cluster-issuer-name
  namespace: development
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: harsh@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: secret-name
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx-class-name
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-class-name
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: cluster-issuer-name
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sub.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: service-name
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sub.example.com
    secretName: secret-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the latest cert-manager.
You'll also need issuer.yaml if you haven't set it up already