# error: error parsing ssl2.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 22: did not find expected key

Tags: kubernetes

> error: error parsing ssl2.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml:
>   line 22: did not find expected key

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: ambassador-certs
  # cert-manager will put the resulting Secret in the same Kubernetes namespace
  # as the Certificate. Therefore you should put this Certificate in the same namespace as Ambassador.
  # eg. if you deploy ambassador to ambassador namespace, you need to change to namespace: ambassador
  namespace: default
spec:
  # naming the secret name certificate ambassador-certs is important because
  # ambassador just look for this particular name
  secretName: ambassador-certs
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  dnsNames:
  - mikiwiki.es
  acme:
    config:
    - http01:
        ingressClass: nginx
      domains:
     - mikiwiki.es
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an [indentation](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534) error on the last line.

Just add one more space on it:

```
      domains:
      - mikiwiki.es
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423312/how-do-i-test-a-clusterissuer-solver/58436097#58436097) stackoverflow post.

You can install jetstack from [here](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/getting-started/install/kubernetes.html), and it will automatically generate the TLS certificate mentioned in the certificate once the DNS is verified