# Istio Kubernetes Ingress with Cert-Manager: no matches for kind "Certificate" in version "certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, istio, cert-manager

I'm trying to configure HTTPS for my K8s/Istio cluster. I'm following this [official tutorial](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-certmgr/) step by step multiple times from scratch and get the same error every time when try to create a Certificate resource.

```
no matches for kind "Certificate" in version "certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
```

I tried to install cert-manager and its CRD manually based on [official docs](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/getting-started/install/kubernetes.html) and no help.

```
cert-manager-5ff755b6d5-9ncgr                               1/1       Running     0          6m55s
cert-manager-cainjector-576978ffc8-4db4l                    1/1       Running     0          6m55s
cert-manager-webhook-c67fbc858-wvtgs                        1/1       Running     0          6m55s
```

Can't find any piece of information regarding this error since it works foe everyone after installing out of the box or after installing cert-manager's CRD.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you to try [this](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/getting-started/install/kubernetes.html) installation for cert-manager and thereafter you can follow [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423312/how-do-i-test-a-clusterissuer-solver/58436097?noredirect=1#comment103215785_58436097) , it will get the issue sorted, I guess. You just need to make few substitutions at places where ingress has to be replaced with istio.

Kindly use

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
```

in clusterissuer, if the apiVersion for clusterIssuer present in that stackoverflow post is not acceptable

Comment: Simply changing apiVersion to yours solved the problem! Thank you!

Comment: The first link is broken

Comment: Nowadays: `cert-manager.io/v1`

Answer (score 1):

```
Use the "kubectl api-versions" to list all the supported api versions.
```

`if the list contains the supported version then you should be able to generate  kind certificates with the corresponding versions  for eg:`
# kubectl api-versions |grep cert
acme.cert-manager.io/v1
cert-manager.io/v1
certificates.k8s.io/v1
certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1`