# Certificate manifest file for k8s using cert-manager

Tags: kubernetes, istio, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

Can any one give me a sample minimalistic manifest files for kind: certificate in K8s using cert-manager. OR suggest me a effective way to use the certificate. May a lead to good documentation would be appreciated

PS: the example in the cert-manager documentation is bit confusing for me.

Comment: try referring this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754832/istio-kubernetes-ingress-with-cert-manager-no-matches-for-kind-certificate-in/58759979#58759979

Answer (score 2):

A small correction to the answer. the apiVersion mentioned in the referenced solution does not work .

I solved it with

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
  namespace: whatever
spec:
  acme:
    email: example@email.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-private-key
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: istio
      selector: {}
```