# error create resource "configmaps" while deploying nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I followed exactly like [this_tutorial](https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/) to deploy nginx ingress contoller. The yaml files used for deploying the ingress controller and describe output are copied to [repo](https://github.com/get2arun/nginx-ingress).

After creating the ingress-controller, pod is running but seeing the below error in the ingress-controller log. The error says serviceaccount "nginx" have no permission to create resource "configmaps" in namespace "ingress".

Question I have,

- what verbs are required in the ClusterRole to allow service account
  "nginx" to create configmaps in my namespace?
- Why serviceaccount "nginx" has to create configmaps in the
  namespace? Because,the ingress controller already has configmap in the namespace then why is the ingress controller tries to create again?

> E1115 15:05:49.678247       7 leaderelection.go:228] error initially
>   creating leader election record: configmaps is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:ingress:nginx" cannot create resource
>   "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress"
>
> (truncated)
>
> I1115 15:05:49.742498       7 controller.go:220] ingress backend
>   successfully reloaded... E1115 15:06:03.379102       7
>   leaderelection.go:228] error initially creating leader election
>   record: configmaps is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:ingress:nginx" cannot create resource
>   "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress"

detailed kubectl log  can be accessed from [this_file](https://github.com/get2arun/nginx-ingress/blob/master/nginx-deployment-describe-pod.log).

[EDIT]

```
root@desktop:~/github/# kubectl get -n ingress all
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/default-backend-7fcd7954d6-gdmvt            1/1     Running   0          3d14h
pod/default-backend-7fcd7954d6-hf65b            1/1     Running   0          3d14h
pod/nginx-ingress-controller-65bfcb57ff-9nz88   1/1     Running   0          2d22h


NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/default-backend   ClusterIP   10.100.x.y   <none>        80/TCP    3d14h


NAME                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/default-backend            2         2         2            2           3d14h
deployment.apps/nginx-ingress-controller   1         1         1            1           2d22h

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/default-backend-7fcd7954d6            2         2         2       3d14h
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-controller-65bfcb57ff   1         1         1       2d22h

root@desktop:~/github# kubectl get -n ingress configmap
NAME                            DATA   AGE
nginx-ingress-controller-conf   1      3d14h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `nginx` service account isn't granted permission to create configmap resources in the namespace.

1. Take a look at this [role definition](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/cloud-generic/role.yaml) and the [role binding](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/cloud-generic/role-binding.yaml) files. Apply them after making any necessary adjustments, like for the service account name (from `nginx-ingress-serviceaccount` to `nginx`).
2. The [Deployment](https://github.com/get2arun/nginx-ingress/blob/master/nginx-ingress-controller-deployment.yaml#L34) configuration has this argument: `--configmap=\$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller-conf`. According to the nginx ingress controller [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/f2d3454520a6fbbda6a48c357da6beae59a8fbf6/docs/user-guide/cli-arguments.md), that is the "...Name of the ConfigMap containing custom global configurations for the controller".

Comment: pt 2, I have updated the $(POD_NAMESPACE) with "ingress" and config map already exists in the "ingress" namespace but as per log, the controller is trying to create configmap again. In the "kubectl get -n ingress all", configmap is not in the output, but it is available in the "kubectl get cs -n ingress".  since the resource configmap exists then why is pod trying to create again.

Comment: for pt1, I will try with the role_definition mentioned in the url and keep updated. thanks.

Comment: pt 1 is accepted answer, I can get through with role definition at https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/cloud-generic/role.yaml

Comment: Glad that it worked. Regarding pt2: this doc has some info about the ConfigMap permissions -  https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/rbac/#namespace-permissions . Looking in the code (https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/leaderelection/resourcelock/configmaplock.go#L69), it appears that an annotation in the configmap named "control-plane.alpha.kubernetes.io/leader" is used as a lock that plays role in the leader election.

Comment: sure will go through configmap stuff. thanks for your help.