# Kubernetes tls/ssl using .pfx certificate

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

For implementing SSL in Kubernetes can we use .pfx certificate file?

Thanks
Girish

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [this](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) installation for cert-manager and thereafter you can follow [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423312/how-do-i-test-a-clusterissuer-solver/58436097?noredirect=1#comment103215785_58436097) , it will get the issue sorted, I guess.

Kindly use

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
```

in clusterissuer, if the apiVersion for clusterIssuer present in that stackoverflow post is not acceptable

Comment: Can we use it for production scenario too?

Comment: yes, it will do auto-renewal also and with ingress you can append annotations for firewall rules too. But LetsEncrypt is freeware and ppl generally use paid CA facilities for production