# Enabling SSL/HTTPS for Zalenium

Tags: kubernetes, zalenium

I hosted Zalenium in Azure Kubernates, and I need to enable SSL.
I see that in the helm charts, there is ingress.yaml with TLS setting, I tried to enable it but apparently nothing happens, does anyone knows what should done ?

Comment: I think it´s more complicated than just enabling something in helm chart, for example take a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/secure-kubernetes-services-with-ingress-tls-letsencrypt/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, SSL/HTTPS is not just about enabling something in helm chart, it´s more complicated.

---

**For example**

You could set up [nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller) with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), which is a free TLS Certificate Authority and you can use it to automatically request and renew Let's Encrypt certificates for public domain names.

Additionally you need [cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager), which is a Kubernetes tool that issues certificates from various certificate providers, including Let's Encrypt.

---

There are several tutorials about this, for example take a look at these

- https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/ingress/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes
- https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/secure-kubernetes-services-with-ingress-tls-letsencrypt/

Additionally take a look at this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436097/11977760) provided by @Tushar Mahajan.