# How to enable HTTPS on Istio Ingress Gateway with kind Service

Tags: yaml, istio

I am trying to enable HTTPS on my Istio Ingress Gateway after installing the service mesh, gateway, and applying a routing policy. The initial Istio installation was done using a profile which includes an `istio-ingressgateway` service. When I do it this way, it creates the ingress gateway as a `Kind: Service` instead of a `Kind: Gateway`.

I looked at this: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/
But, the tutorial only describes how to apply the certificate to a Gateway kind and not a Service kind.

What is the proper way to apply the SSL certificate to an ingress gateway service or is there a better way to approach this?

[Istio Profile YAML](https://pastebin.com/GULJ2zHC)

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Problem Solved.

I went back through the tutorial last night after going down the path of trying to create a clusterIssuer and installing cert manager etc with poor results (The certificate never got accepted by the Certificate Authority for some reason so I only had the key file and an empty cert file). It ended up being easier to create my own certificate.

The issue was that I was referencing the TLS port in my virtual service when I only needed to point towards the port of the service where I was trying to send traffic from the gateway.

This article helped me understand better: [Secure Ingress -Istio By Example](https://istiobyexample.dev/secure-ingress/) along with the official Istio Secure-Ingress tutorial I linked above already.

From there I just created a new secret, ran a script that creates a working certificate (basically just a bash script that follows the steps from the Istio tutorial), and then made sure the credential name in my gateway file matched the new secret I created.

Comment: does the load balancer accept certificates? if so, apply it as normal.

Comment: What is the normal way though? I followed the tutorial but it doesn't seem to work. For more context, when trying to curl the external IP for the istio-ingressgateway loadbalancer, this is the response:
`LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to [EXTERNAL IP]`

Comment: The normal way would be to set up an external LB pointing to istio-ingressgateway; with TLS termination on the LB. The certs would be stored in the LB, and further connection would go on HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you deployed the istio setup, it will create

- kind: Service, istio-ingressgateway
- kind: deployemnt , istio-ingressgateway

then you can create the below with https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/, this will configure your ssl.

- kind: Secret,  in namespace: istio-system
- kind: gateway, with the above secrets in it referred.
- kind: Virtual Service, linked to this gateway , and dest. application.

Answer (score 1):

Some concepts are slightly confused:

- The Gateway custom resource will configure the istio-ingressgateway, meanwhile
- The Kubernetes Service will create an externally accessible IP.

Using the externally accessible IP, the traffic will be sent to the istio-ingressgateway, where your certificates are configured using the Gateway CR and you will have an HTTPS connection.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to simply follow the below mentioned steps -

Install cert-manager from [here](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) using the steps those are helm chart based

The you can follow [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423312/how-do-i-test-a-clusterissuer-solver/58436097?noredirect=1#comment103215785_58436097) post

Note that - you need not create the tls secret here, cert-manager will auto create the secret by name mentioned in your certificate, cert-manager will carryout acme challenge once you patch the secret name to TLS and once it gets successful, the certificate acquires ready state.

use

```
cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
```

this api version in cluster issuer, if the one mentioned there only is not acceptable