# Problems when upgrade kube-lego to cert-manager

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, cert-manager, kube-lego

I use kube-lego in 0.1.5-a9592932 version, but this service are deprecated and now the time has come for migrate for cert-manger. When testing migrate I lost the secret "kube-lego-account", but I need this! It's possible forcing generate the secret? I restarted the kube-lego and check the logs and found this:

```
Attempting to create new secret" context=secret name=kube-lego-account namespace=default
```

But the secret not was created. How can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

let's take an another path, Letsencrypt official docs say that they won't be supporting any longer for below 0.8 versions, so I recommend you to install cert-manager provided by Jetstack, that you can find [here](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/), to install the helm chart for it.

The follow [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423312/how-do-i-test-a-clusterissuer-solver/58436097?noredirect=1#comment103215785_58436097), for configurations, note that if the api version mentioned in that post doesn't support in case of cluster issuer, then rather use

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
```

Note that , the tls secret name mentioned in the certificate will be auto-generated by cert-manager, and it automatically starts an acme-challenge to validate the domain, once you patch that secret name to the TLS in your ingress rule.

It shall solve the issue and the certificate's status will change to ready after the domain verification

Comment: Thanks your contribute.