# Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code '404', expected '200'

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cert-manager

I just set up cert-manager on Kubernetes GCP but when I check my logs I get this error:

```
cert-manager/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="wrong status code '404', expected '200'" "dnsName"="api.lumiwealth.com" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="test-certificate-h4m8c-1804713970-576085961" "resource_namespace"="backend" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
```

From what I can tell the issue is that the ingress that gets created does not have access to the external internet. I confirmed this by running this in Terminal:

```
curl http://api.lumiwealth.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/vhoLg-lNAgXAwEJlknfBbRlYuKuHBakgeG_d40c09Zk
```

Which returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/vhoLg-lNAgXAwEJlknfBbRlYuKuHBakgeG_d40c09Zk</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are my YAML files:

Issuer:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata: 
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec: 
  acme: 
    email: "rob@lumiwealth.com"
    privateKeySecretRef: 
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    server: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: ingress-gce
```

Test certificate:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: test-certificate
  namespace: backend
spec:
  secretName: certificate-test
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  dnsNames:
  - api.lumiwealth.com
```

When I `kubectl apply` the certificate it creates an ingress in GCP that looks like this (but doesn't seem to have network access? I'm not sure how it could have possibly gotten the IP address from my DNS)

[image]

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: I think you can not do this without internet access.

Comment: @xirehat how can i add that in GCP? (and how do i even know whether I have it?)

Comment: Try this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080246/cert-manager-challenge-pending-kubernetes) & [Link](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/4648) may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Can you post Ingress manifest? Especially the part with host rules is interesting.
Also, are there errors in the ingress logs?

Comment: In addition to the links provided by @VeeraNagireddy, consider read [this related Github issue](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/2517),  I think it could be of help.

Comment: try DNS-01 method http should work try deleting Clusterissuer, certificate and apply again, and make sure ingress have default backend that might could help incase of thwoing the 404.

Comment: Quick question, can you query other services such as google.com? Aka can you get "out" of your cluster in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is a routing issue rather than a network issue.

When you query

```
curl http://api.lumiwealth.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/vhoLg-lNAgXAwEJlknfBbRlYuKuHBakgeG_d40c09Zk
```

This does indeed work and can exit the cluster and the broader internet. What that query does is that then it tries to access the challenge file within the cluster.

Would you kindly check for the values of

```
kubectl -A get challenges
```

To make sure that there is only one set of challenges?, if there are more you may want to delete everything and start over.

So all you have to do is modify your ingress routes to capture the route

```
.well-known/acme-challenge/*
```

This has to be routed to the ACME solver pod/service within your cluster.

The basic troubleshooting steps for https01 [Docs](https://cert-manager.io/docs/troubleshooting/acme/#got-404-status-code)

- You can access the URL from the public internet
- The ACME solver pod is up and running
- Use kubectl describe ingress to check the status of the HTTP01 solver ingress. (unless you use acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place, then check the same ingress as your domain)

Comment: The result of get challenges was this:
NAME                                           STATE     DOMAIN               AGE
test-certificate-9hx4t-1804713970-2259448401   pending   api.lumiwealth.com   5d
Also the ingress route seems to point at cm-acme-http-solver and the pod. Any idea how to diagnose this part?

Comment: It's 5Days old and is stuck on pending, I would delete any challenge over the hour. You will have to get the url 

```
http://api.lumiwealth.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/$RANDOM_HASH
```

To resolve, you will have to play with your ingress rules to route this correctly for the http to work I would recommend to do it through dns instead if you can, if not you have to go through the routing debugging.

Comment: Which Ingress routes are you referring to? I did not find an Ingress for cert-manager in my installation & it does not seem reasonable to me to fiddle with every single Helm installation on my instance, just to get this route working. This does not sound right, at all.

Comment: Well you don't have to fiddle with all of them, just the one that routes from the internet into the acme secret, that's how the http01 validation works, the dns one is preferable so you don't have to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, spent a few hours troubleshooting this.

I have the same issue and I am using nginx controller and the ingress is managed by ArgoCD where Sync Policy is automatic and I have put this line in my ingress manifest:

> acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"

This has caused the challenge route to be replaced just right after it was added into the ingress.

So when Let's Encrypt is hitting that path, it actually went into the my system pod instead of the acme http solver pod and of course my pod wouldn't have the route and gave a 404, hence the error Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code '404', expected '200'

While checking the logs in ingress controller helps, it was when I realise the checks actually went into my service pod have me to realise this.

Odd case but hope it still helps some one out there.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because in the DNS record i was aiming for staging instead of production.

run `curl -v https://yourdomainnamehere.com` and check the if the domain name matches the subject.