# Azure kubernetes - Istio certificate installation?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, istio, azure-aks

I am using ISTIO for service mesh in Azure kubernetes. I have configured private DNS to setup the FQDN. Currently the application is accessible over http protocol(eg: http://myapp.contoso.com) and I would like to be secured with https protocol(eg: https://myapp.contoso.com).

I know I have to change the service port to 443 to support https protocol however how/where do I install the SSL certificate for the application (eg: https://myapp.contoso.com)? Is there anything else to be done as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here [Securing Your Istio Ingress Gateway with HTTPS](https://programmaticponderings.com/2019/01/03/securing-your-istio-gateway-with-https/amp/)

There is istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/) about that.

Answer (score 2):

That will depend on where do you want the SSL termination to happen, if you want that to happen inside the Azure kubernetes network, then you can do SSL termination at ingress layer.

Or otherwise you can also do the termination at application gateway layer of Azure ( if you want to avail this service from azure, the redirection from http to https, basic firewall features and adding the pfx certificates at the listeners can be done), ingress can also take care of these things although.

You can install the let's encrypt certificates by using [this helm chart](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/getting-started/install/kubernetes.html) and for further steps you can follow [this stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423312/how-do-i-test-a-clusterissuer-solver/58436097?noredirect=1#comment103215785_58436097), it shall help you in creating configurations for Istio, ppl have used this solution for Istio as well before