# cert-manager - Acme Http Solver Returns 404

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

Have a kubernetes cluster with an nginx ingress to a service which I am trying to set up with https access using `cert-manager` and ACME `ClusterIssuer`.

The steps I have followed from cert-manager I am reasonably happy with but I am currently at the stage where a challenge is made to http solver which cert-manager has configured in the cluster as part of the challenge process. When I describe the service's generated challenge I see that its state is pending with:

```
Reason:      Waiting for http-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request 'http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/nDWOHEMXgy70_wxi53ijEKjUHFlzg_UJJS-sv_ahGzg': Get "http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/nDWOHEMXgy70_wxi53ijEKjUHFlzg_UJJS-sv_ahGzg": dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xxx:80: connect: connection timed out
```

When I call the solver's url from my k8s host server:

```
curl -H "Host: www.example.com" http://192.168.1.11:31344/.well-known/acme-challenge/nDWOHEMXgy70_wxi53ijEKjUHFlzg_UJJS-sv_ahGzg
```

I get a 200 ok back.

NOTE: The address 192.168.1.11 is the ip of the k8s node on which the http solver pod is running. And port 31344 is the internal port of the nodeIp service for the http solver pod.

I am trying to figure out why the challenge itself times out and not get a 200 back.

I have tested the http solver's url from my mobile phone over 4g (instead of wifi) and this way I get 200 OK so, this tells me that the http solver is reachable from the outside through the firewall and via nginx into the service and pod right? And so, if this is the case then what other reason(s) could there be for Let's Encrypt not being able to retrieve the token from the same URL?

--- CURRENT CONFIGS ---

Cluster Issuer:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
 name: letsencrypt-staging
 namespace: cert-manager
spec:
 acme:
   # The ACME server URL
   server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
   # Email address used for ACME registration
   email: my.address@example.com
   # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
   privateKeySecretRef:
     name: letsencrypt-staging
   # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
   solvers:
   - selector: {}
     http01:
       ingress:
         class: nginx
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ing-myservice-web
  namespace: myservice
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: secret-myservice-web-tls
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: svc-myservice-web
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
  - host: www.example.co.uk
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: svc-myservice-web
            servicePort: 8080
          path: /
```

Comment: I have managed to prove that the http solver pod is running correctly by running the curl command as follows: `curl -I -H "Host: www.place.com" http://192.168.1.11:30421/.well-known/acme-challenge/nDWOHEMXgy70_wxi53ijEKjUHFlzg_UJJS-sv_ahGzg`. This call return 200 OK.

Comment: With regards to the challenge status of 404 I am thinking that this might be because it is not possible to call external ip address (which my domain points to) from within my own network? i.e. from behind the firewall?

Comment: I have tested the http solver's url from my mobile phone over 4g (instead of wifi) so this proves that the http solver is reachable through the firewall and via nginx into the service and pod which is good but as my last comment states, I don't think it is possible to call the http solver's challenge url from within my own network. So how does one work around this?

Comment: The text in https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge states that it is Let's Encrypt that attempts to retrieve the token from the http solver's url so my last comment is void. However, I can retrieve the token from my mobile phone over 4g (i.e. externally) so why can't Let's Encrypt?

Comment: 1. Please edit your question with all the necessary info instead of posting it as a comment. Try to keep it short and clear. 2. Provide your configs/yamls and steps to reproduce your issue. We can't help much based on what you have given us.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I've re-worded the post's problem question and added ClusterIssuer, Ingress configs as per your suggestions. Would inclusion of any other configs also help?

Comment: hey check this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423312/how-do-i-test-a-clusterissuer-solver/58436097?noredirect=1#comment103215785_58436097 , I guess this shall help

Comment: @TusharMahajan, I think the post you linked is for a different scenario where the `nginx controller` is `LoadBalance`d with a public provider and where the `http solver` is able to call out to the world wide web and back in again (which my ISP does not allow).

Answer (score 5):

After reading up about various different aspects of how `cert-manager` works, reading up about other peoples' similar issues on other posts and getting a better understanding on how my network is set up and is seen from the outside, I present below what I've learnt about my setup and thereafter what I did in order to get `cert-manager` working for my domain services in the k8s cluster within.

**Setup:**

- kubernetes cluster with backend services fronted by `nginx` ingress controller with a `NodePort` service exposing ports 25080 and 25443 for http and https respectively.
- kubernetes cluster in private network behind ISP's public IP.

**Solution:**

- Configured a local `http proxy` running on port 80 outside the k8s cluster which forwards requests to the `nginx controller`'s `NodePort` IP and port 25080.
- Configured `bind9` on my network to point www to host where local `http proxy` is running.
- Configured the k8s cluster's `CoreDNS` to point to `bind9` host (Instead of 8.8.4.4, etc.)
- Configured my private network's entry point router to send any address port 80 to `nginx controller`'s `NodePort` IP and port 25080.
- Configured my private network's entry point router to send any address port 443 to `nginx controller`'s `NodePort` IP and port 25443.

The main reason for this solution is that my ISP does not allow hosts within my private network to call out and back into the network via the network's public IP address. (I believe this is quite common for ISPs and it's called Harpining or NAT Loopback, and some routers have the functionality to turn it on).

So, in order for the `cert-manager`'s `http solver` pod (running within the k8s cluster) to be able to complete the challenge it was necessary for it to be able reach the `nginx controller` by forcing the network routing for www via the locally hosted `http proxy` instead of going out to the world wide web and back in again (which my ISP does not allow).

With this solution in place the `http solver` pod was able to complete the challenge and thereafter `cert-manager` was able to issue certificates successfully.

I am sure (and I hope) there are better and cleaner solutions to solve this sort of scenario out there but I have not come across any myself yet so this is the solution I currently have in place.