# Two ingress resources for a single wildcard certificate

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I am working on an application, which is running on nginx ingress.
I'd like to be able to provision a shared SSL certificate for all of the subdomains running that application.

For this purpose I have used, Wildcard certificate with Let's Encrypt and Cert manager.
After all the steup, I get my certificate to be true and my sub domains defined in a ingress resource file have a valid certificate.

But when I define an extra ingress resource file with more subdomains, they do not get a valid certificate.

Is there any limitation for one ingress file for one wildcard certificate?

Cert-manager version: 1.0.4
Kubernetes version: 1.16

Comment: this shall not happen, there is no such restriction

Comment: I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423312/how-do-i-test-a-clusterissuer-solver/58436097?noredirect=1#comment103215785_58436097 shall help you

Comment: Does @TusharMahajan comment was helpful? Can you share your current configuration?